# Searching through multiple attributes

Tags: javascript, jquery, search, attr

I have a search function that can quite happily search through a list divs for one data-attribute, below is the code that is working.

```
$(".classToSearch").each(function(){
    if ($(this).attr('data-attribute1').search(new RegExp(filter, "i")) < 0) {
        $(this).animate({opacity:0.1},100);
    } else {
        $(this).animate({opacity:0.5},100);
    }
});
```

What I would like for the search function is to be able to search through multiple data-attributes. I've tried a range of different formats but I can't get it to work. Below is what I thought it should look like.

```
$(this).attr('data-attribute1','data-attribute2','data-attribute3')
```

or

```
$(this).attr('data-attribute1'||'data-attribute2'||'data-attribute3')
```

But I'm thinking I'm going to need a for loop of some kind.  Any help would be appreciated.

**----------EDIT-------------**

**MY SOLUTION**
This allows the search box to search all the data attributes.

```
$(".classToSearch").each(function(){
        if ($(this).attr('data-attribute1').search(new RegExp(filter, "i")) < 0 &&
            $(this).attr('data-attribute2').search(new RegExp(filter, "i")) < 0 &&
            $(this).attr('data-attribute3').search(new RegExp(filter, "i")) < 0 &&         
            ) {
            $(this).animate({opacity:0.1},100);
        } else {
            $(this).animate({opacity:0.5},100);
        }
    });
```

Comment: Do you mean e.g. `if( $(this).attr('data-attr1').search(..) || $(this).attr('data-attr2').search(..) ) {} else {}`? I'm only putting suggestions, perhaps it's even possible to do `[ $(this).attr('data-attrib1'), $(this).attr('data-attr2'), $(this).attr('data-attr3') ].search(..)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use `.data()` to access those attributes a little easier and then collect them into an array from which you perform the regular expression test on each of them:

```
var $this = $(this),
attribs = [$this.data('attribute1'), $this.data('attribute2'), $this.data('attribute3')],
re = new RegExp(filter, "i");

if (attribs.some(function() {
    return this.match(re);
})) {
    // some attributes matched the filter
} else {
    // no attributes matched the filter
}
```

See also: [`Array.some()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/some)

Comment: thanks for this solution, I've implemented it a bit differently by listing each of the data fields separately and testing them with regex one by one, I can't seem to get it to work by using an array. I will look at this again in the future to have it work a bit nicer.

**I've edited my description to show the solution that worked for me. **

Answer (score 0):

Have you looked at this...

http://api.jquery.com/multiple-attribute-selector/

Seems to be what your after.

But maybe a bit more like...

```
if ($(this).has([attr1],[attr2])){
   //do stuff
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you don't know the attribute names ahead of time, or you don't want to know them, just an arbitrary set of attributes where you want to search the value then something like this

```
    $(".classToSearch").each(function() {
        var _in = $(this).text();
        $.each($(this).data(), function(k, v) {
            if (v == find) {
                // ...
            }
        });
    });
```

In JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/yJLzQ/1/